# How get the data using MVC- Servlets, JPS and JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I have JSP page that has links (When people click on the link it is supposed to go to a servlet and then Bean class and DB Connection class to pull the data)..and when a user clicks on the like I tried to display the page using AJAX...however i am currently not getting any data/page pulled. Can someone please explain on how to achive this?

here is the link i have in my HTML page..but when i click on it is not showing up anything.

```
 <a href="myservlet" onclick="grabfile(this.href); return false;">VT </a>
```

Thanks for your help

Sorry here is my code

```
public class VacationTrackerDAO {

public static List<VactionTrackerBean> list() throws SQLException{
    List<VactionTrackerBean> appr= new ArrayList<VactionTrackerBean>();

    try{

        DBConnection conObj=new DBConnection(); 
        Connection dbCon= conObj.getCon();
        Statement stmt=conObj.getStmt();
        String queryCPList="select * from Capacity_Plan";
        String queryApprList="Select First_Last_Name from Vacation_Approvers";
        PreparedStatement preStmtCPList=dbCon.prepareStatement(queryCPList);//get metadat
        PreparedStatement preStmtApprList=dbCon.prepareStatement(queryApprList);//get names
        ResultSet rsCPList=preStmtCPList.executeQuery();
        ResultSet rsApprList=preStmtCPList.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData metaCPList=rsCPList.getMetaData();

        VactionTrackerBean vtBean=new VactionTrackerBean();
        while(rsApprList.next()){
            vtBean.setApprover((rsApprList.getString("First_Last_Name")));
            appr.add(vtBean);
        }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("In the Vacation TrackerDAO.java class:"+e);
}
return appr;
}
}
```

Here is my Servlets which gets the request.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try{

    List<VactionTrackerBean> vacBean=VacationTrackerDAO.list();
    request.setAttribute("vacTracker", vacBean);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/VacationTracker.jsp").forward(request,response);

    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error in VacationTracker.java due to VactionTrackerDA.java:"+e);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/Error.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
```

Here is the code that i have in the JSP page.

```
<li>  <a href="Main.jsp" > home </a>        </li>
<li><a href="VacationTracker" onclick="grabfile(this.href); return false;">Vacation     Tracker </a>  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code for my Javascript

```
function getHTTPObject(){

var xhr=false;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

    xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();

} else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    try{
        xhr= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

    } catch(e){
        try{
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            xhr=false;
        }
    } 

}

return xhr;
```

}

```
function grabfile(file){
var request=getHTTPObject();
if(request){

    request.onreadystatechange=function(){ displayResponse(request);};


}
request.open("POST",file,true);
request.send(null);
```

}

```
function displayResponse(request){

if(request.readyState==4){
    if(request.status==200){

        document.getElementById    ("middle_sub").innerHTML=request.responseText;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Far too broad - you must provide the relevant parts of your code. Given just one link it's not even possible to guess what might go wrong!

Comment: Almost duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443896/mvc-servlets-jsp-no-output